# Background process wont clear memory. Is it a good idea to kill my own process on Android?

Tags: android, service, background, android-widget

I have an app that has a widget. In the main app, I have an ad framework (cannot be edited due to licence) that is accumulatively leaking approx 1MB every time I exit the app. It appears one of its threads are running in the background (unnecessarily) that will keep its process and these threads will be created again when I launch the app.

Is it a good idea to call

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

in the onDestroy method of my main activity?

Also, would doing this kill my widget's service as well?

Comment: The best idea is probably to nag the developers of the third-party framework to fix their code.

Comment: Is it a good idea?  No.  The framework needs to be fixed or removed.  Anything else is a dirty hack that gives your app (and Android) a bad name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the intent concept to use the background processing or u can also develop service that will be executing your third party framework in background.

Comment: Thank you for you response, the frame work is an ad framework, therefore, it should load a new one every time and my users don't like having apps running in the background constantly. Also, the ad uses like 10% of the cpu every 3 seconds. I need a way to kill it and my code above seems to work